# Syntax highlight for code - 4 clicks until I find the documentation

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, help

Very often, I mix Java/SQL/XML code and I'd like to help Code Prettify to assess what type of code I'm writing, as it's not good in guessing mixed code. I didn't even know until asking this question, that it actually doesn't guess, but the Stack Overflow tags indicate the language. Also, I think many users don't know there is such a prettify language hinting feature.

And I keep forgetting how it works, as this is entirely different on every forum/blog software. So I have to look it up. Check out the number of required steps:

### Step 1 - The obvious one

[image]

### Step 2 - OK, I see. This step saves some space

[image]

### Step 3 - Why is Code Prettify info missing here?

[image]

### Step 4 - If I haven't lost attention yet... Scroll to the bottom

[image]

### Step 5 - Another expand button

[image]

---

I think this information deserves more importance, at least to hint that such a thing exists. I'd put it in step 3

Comment: *"And I keep forgetting how it works, as this is entirely different on every forum/blog software."* Well then, the solution seems obvious. Stop using those other forums/blog software and share all your love with Stack Overflow all the time!

Comment: Yeah, but Stack Overflow doesn't like (subjective) forum questions, or spam, so I have to go elsewhere from time to time ;-)

Comment: You really need to hint that often? It's not in the basic help because it's supposed to be really rare

Comment: @Michael: Well the point is (I think) that tags are used for hinting. But I'm not always tagging a question as `SQL` just because it contains SQL. Also, I work with several languages, mostly, so then at least one code block is always badly formatted... So yes, for me, I have to add those hints in one out of three questions. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026331/how-to-parse-a-documentfragment-with-with-the-java-standard-dom-api

Comment: @Michael: But the problem is also that formatted code in answers might not match the tag itself and might be formatted badly...